# C# 20,000 records selected from oracle need to be inserted into SQL2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, oracle, bulkinsert

i have a console app in c# that extracts 20 fields from an oracle DB witht he code below and i wanted an efficient way to insert them into SQL 2005.

i dotn want to insert each one of the 20,000 within the while loop, obviously. i was thinking to change the code to use a data set to cache all the records and then do a bulk insert...

thoughts?

pseudo code would be nice since i am new to oracle.

this is my code where i was testing getting a connection to oracle and seeing if i can view the data... now i can view it i want to get it out and into sql2005... what do i do from here?

```
static void getData()
{
    string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection())
    {
        connection.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        connection.Open();

        OracleCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM BUG";
        command.CommandText = sql;

        OracleDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //string myField = (string)reader["Project"];
            string myField = reader[0].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(myField);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Assuming permissions, you could've used a Linked Server instance from SQL Server (or a dblink from Oracle) to directly connect the databases for importing the data.

Comment: If you're going to do this on a regular basis, then consider using SSIS. This sort of thing is a strength of it, and it will gladly optimize for bulk inserts.

Comment: I'd recommend wrapping your `OracleDataReader reader = ...` in a `using`, as well.

Comment: i would love to look into SSIS but cant for the life of me get SQL2005 to link to oracle such that i can access the data at all. I got it connected with a net connection string and am able to access the oracle data in c# code.

Comment: Using SSIS isn't the same as using Linked Server. I agree that Linked server is a bit of voodoo which I've never been successful at running but I'm sure that's my failing not the technology. SSIS will just treat Oracle as an external data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a CSV file and then use BULK INSERT to insert the file into SQL Server. Have a look [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-bulk-insert-to-load-a-text-file) for an example.

Comment: can you explain a bit more on how to generate the csv. I am clear on how to import it from the article (thanks)

Comment: If you have connect and select privs on the oracle db, you can probably use the UTL_FILE package to extract the data as a csv file. You'd probably need admin rights to the host/server as well.
If not, try the SQL Developer app for Oracle DB, you can extract file as CSV via the app.

Answer (score 0):

The "bulk" insert with the cached Dataset will work exactly like the while loop you are not wanting to write! The problem is that you'll lose control of the process if you try to use the "bulk" insert of the Dataset class. It is extraneous work in the end.

Maybe the best solution is to use a DataWriter so that you have complete control and no Dataset overhead.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually do 100-1000 inserts per sql batch. Just generate multiple inserts, then submit. Pregenerate the next SELECT batch WHILE THE FIRST EXECUTES.

Comment: .NET provider does not work with batches, how can we do it? I have never been able to run batches.